# Mongodb Atlas: MongoError: user is not allowed to do action [insert] on [test.products]

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have set the necessary permissions on mongodb atlas.i am trying to write to a database test from node.js, this is code in my 
products.js:

```
router.post('/:productId', (req ,res ,next) => {
  const id = req.params.productId;
  Product.findById(id)
  .exec()
  .then(doc=> {console.log(doc);
  res.status(200).json(doc).catch(err => console.log(err))
  })
  .catch(err =>{ console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({error: err});

  })
```

});

Terminal shows the error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: user is not allowed to do action [insert] on [test.products]
    at C:\Users\Hiary\Documents\rest-api\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:598:61
    at authenticateStragglers (C:\Users\Hiary\Documents\rest-api\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:516:16)
    at Connection.messageHandler (C:\Users\Hiary\Documents\rest-api\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:552:5)
    at emitMessageHandler (C:\Users\Hiary\Documents\rest-api\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:309:10)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Hiary\Documents\rest-api\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:452:17)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:180:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:274:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:261:11)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:218:10)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:581:20)
(node:21692) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
```

I have given permissions as shown in below screenshot [image]

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if you have a user that only has permission to a certain database but you do not include this in your connection string. E.g. the connection string atlas will recommend is

mongodb+srv://:@productive.abcd.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority

but if your user only has access to the database "my-database" the connection string should look like this

mongodb+srv://:@productive.abcd.mongodb.net/**my-database**?retryWrites=true&w=majority

Answer (score 1):

1.Sign-In your MongoDB Atlas account
2.Clicked on Database Access > Database Users > EDIT actions for certain user > Specific Privileges > Add Specific Privilege > readWriteAnyDatabase (Select Role) > Update User

Answer (score 0):

`Mongodb` Atlas doesn't seem to work with postman,or have some kind of problem with their setup,I now have my `mondgodb` hosted with `mLab` and everything works fine,didn't have to change my code

Answer (score -1):

When Copying the connection string compatible with your driver version from mongodb.Atlas choose the first one, if it is not working choose the second.

Comment: Please explain your answer, I can't see the relation between your answer and the question.

Answer (score -1):

Just add mongodb rules (readWriteAnyDatabase@Admin) in Database access..
[just do it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAAXL.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).